# why my plate turn to normal map in object mode?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

[image: this is my object mode and my node editor screen also]

so as i was following a tutorial on blender guru (youtube channel) when i added the normal map to my wood texture , this happen !!!
when i render every thing is okay and it's beautiful but it's annoying me so much when editing and modeling i see the normal map , why is that's happening !?
i tried to replace the images again or tweak the options , but none work , can you help me please !?

Comment: As you enabled Texture shading mode, Blender shows you currently selected texture in the Node editor. Enable Solid shading mode and it will show solid grey colors. This affects only viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening like that because you have selected the normal map image node in the Node Editor. If you click the object texture node in the node editor, that active node will be displayed in the viewport.

EDIT:[image]

Comment: But even when I close the node editor it's still there , and when I click the texture image it appears  in view port so how to deactivate it ?

Comment: You should click on the node which contains your image texture.

Comment: I did that but instead of my normal map is in the viewport , my wood image texture is in the viewport , I only want to see my plate white and gray object like the cup and the donnate !!

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it solves your problem, mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: That's what I did in my gif at last :)